# How to give the same behavior of an input hidden and of a custom label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to give the same behavior of a file type input button with style = "display: none;" To a custom label? That is, the label and the input can have the same actions even though the input is hidden.
Below my html code:

```
<label for="model1" class="uploadFile">File...</label>
<input id="model1" type="file" name="model1" class="model1" style="display:none;" required="true"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

it is quite easy with jQuery:

```js
$('#model1Label').on('click', function(){
    $('#model1').triggerHandler('click');
    
    //seems not to work consistently on chrome (only for file inputs?)
    //$('#model1').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="model1Label" for="model1" class="uploadFile">File...</label>
<input id="model1" type="file" name="model1" class="model1" style="display:none;" required="true"  />
```

EDIT: as suggested by SKSpall, modified the trigger function for a weird behaviour on at least chrome

Comment: The file dialog box appears two times after clicking Cancel/Open i.e. If I click Cancel once, it appears again and when I click Cancel again, it goes away. It's good to use triggerHandler method as .triggerHandler() does not cause the default behavior of an event to occur. $('#model1').triggerHandler('click'); should work perfect.

Comment: @SKSpall thx, ill update the answer, it works perfectly fine here with firefox, but some spywares like chrome might behave weirdly :D

Comment: Yeah, I tested in Chrome. :P Apart from Chrome, this works fine in FF and IE. triggerHandler works fine in all three.